# Can't create handler inside thread Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm rewriting an Android app using retrofit + RxJava. I'm new about Retrofit and RxJava, so I have some problem and I can't solve the error:"
`Can't create handler inside thread Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()`".

I get the error in this piece of code:

```
String finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE = HTTP_PATH_GETAREE;
                disposable = apiInterface.getInfoViaggio(HTTP_PATH_GETINFOVIAGGIO)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .flatMap(response -> {
                            if (response.getReturnCode() < 0){
                                Log.d("TAG1","response "+response.getReturnCode());
                                soundEffectError = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.wronglongbuzzer);
                                soundEffectError.start();
                                pulisciDatiViaggio(response.getReturnMessage());

                            }
                            else {
                                editor.putInt("out_rc", response.getReturnCode()).commit();
                                returnMessage = response.getReturnMessage();
                            }
                            return apiInterface.getAree(finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE);
                        })
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .map(areas -> areas)
                        .subscribe(this::handlerResponse,this::handlerError);
            }
```

I'm testing this condition `response.getReturnCode() < 0` and I get the error, instead the condition > 0 works fine.
I think that I'm not managing in the right way `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.
I would like to understard a smart way to manage when I have more than a call and I need to test some condition inside.

My code:

```
  public class DatiViaggioRepo {
        
            private static final String MY_PREFS = "SAVE_VALUE";
            private static final String MY_CONFIG = "SAVE_VALUE_CONFIG";
            private Disposable disposable;
            private ApiInterface apiInterface;
            private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            private SharedPreferences prefs, preConf;
            private SharedPreferences.Editor editor, config;
            private Context context;
            private MediaPlayer soundEffectError, soundEffetctDistintaLetta;
            private EditText mViaggio, mData, mCodCliente;
            private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter, arrayAdapterList;;
            private AutoCompleteTextView act;
            private LinkedList<Area> areas;
            private String[] infoList;
            private List<String> info_list;
            private ListView simpleList;
            private String returnMessage;
            private Button btnContViaggio;
        
        
            public DatiViaggioRepo(ApiInterface apiInterface, Context context){
                this.apiInterface = apiInterface;
                this.context = context;
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                preConf = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_CONFIG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = prefs.edit();
                config = preConf.edit();
            }
        
        
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            public void getDatiViaggio(String baseurl, AutoCompleteTextView act, EditText mViaggio, EditText mData,
                                       EditText mCodCliente, ListView simpleList, Button btnContViaggio){
        
                this.act = act;
                this.mViaggio = mViaggio;
                this.mData = mData;
                this.mCodCliente = mCodCliente;
                this.simpleList = simpleList;
                this.btnContViaggio = btnContViaggio;
                CompositeDisposable cd = new CompositeDisposable();
                String HTTP_PATH_GETINFOVIAGGIO = null;
                String HTTP_PATH_GETAREE = null;
        
                String codViaggio = mViaggio.getText().toString().trim();
                String idTerminale = preConf.getString("idTerminale","0");
        
                try {
                    HTTP_PATH_GETINFOVIAGGIO  = baseurl + "/gv/gestViaggi?p_cmd=2&p_p1=" + URLEncoder.encode(codViaggio,"UTF-8")
                                                                            +"&p_p2=" + URLEncoder.encode(idTerminale,"UTF-8");
        
                    HTTP_PATH_GETAREE = baseurl + "/aree/getAree?p1=" + URLEncoder.encode(codViaggio,"UTF-8") + "&p2=.";
        
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Something unexpected happened to our request: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        
                String finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE = HTTP_PATH_GETAREE;
                disposable = apiInterface.getInfoViaggio(HTTP_PATH_GETINFOVIAGGIO)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .flatMap(response -> {
                            if (response.getReturnCode() < 0){
                                Log.d("TAG1","response "+response.getReturnCode());
                                soundEffectError = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.wronglongbuzzer);
                                soundEffectError.start();
                                pulisciDatiViaggio(response.getReturnMessage());
        
                            }
                            else {
                                editor.putInt("out_rc", response.getReturnCode()).commit();
                                returnMessage = response.getReturnMessage();
                            }
                            return apiInterface.getAree(finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE);
                        })
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .map(areas -> areas)
                        .subscribe(this::handlerResponse,this::handlerError);
            }
        
        
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            private void handlerResponse(Area.ElencoAree elencoAree) {
                Log.d("TAG3","elenco aree "+elencoAree);
                if (elencoAree != null) {
                    mostraDatiViaggio(returnMessage);
                    mostraAree(elencoAree);
                    btnContViaggio.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    String msg = "Aree non caricate per questo Viaggio";
                    message(msg, () -> {
                        soundEffectError = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.wronglongbuzzer);
                        soundEffectError.start();
                        pulisciDatiViaggio(msg);
                    });
                }
            }
        
            private void handlerError(Throwable t) {
                Log.d("TAG4","Something unexpected happened to our request: "+t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Something unexpected happened to our request: "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
           
            private void pulisciDatiViaggio(String msg){
        
                message(msg, new Cb() {
                    @Override
                    public void onOkCliked() {
                        mViaggio.getText().clear();
                        mViaggio.requestFocus();
                        mData.getText().clear();
                        mCodCliente.getText().clear();
        
                        if (info_list != null && !info_list.isEmpty()) {
                            info_list.clear();
                            arrayAdapterList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        if (act.getText().length()>0) {
                            act.getText().clear();
                            areas.clear();
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
        
            }
        
        
            private void mostraDatiViaggio(String out_msg){
        
                String[] datiPrelievo;
                datiPrelievo = out_msg.split(";");
        
                mData.setText(datiPrelievo[0]);
                mCodCliente.setText(datiPrelievo[1]);
                infoList = Arrays.copyOfRange(datiPrelievo,2,datiPrelievo.length);
                info_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(infoList));
                arrayAdapterList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.activity_listview, R.id.textView, info_list);
                simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapterList);
            }
        
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            private void mostraAree(Area.ElencoAree elencoAree){
        
                String firstNArea = elencoAree.getListaAree().get(0).getnArea();
                String firstDescArea = elencoAree.getListaAree().get(0).getDescArea();
                editor.putString("nArea",firstNArea).commit(); 
                editor.putString("descrArea",firstDescArea).commit();
                List<String> ea = elencoAree.getListaAree().stream().map(x->x.getDescArea()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.option_item, ea);
            
                act.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                act.requestFocus();
                act.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
                    /**Viene intercettata la scelta dell'area e salvata*/
                    editor.putString("nArea", elencoAree.getListaAree().get(i).getnArea()).commit();
                    editor.putString("descrArea", elencoAree.getListaAree().get(i).getDescArea()).commit();
                });
                soundEffetctDistintaLetta = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.beep_01a_short);
                soundEffetctDistintaLetta.start();
            }
        
        
            private interface Cb{
                void onOkCliked();
            }
        
            void message(String msg, Cb cb) {
                builder.setMessage(msg)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, id) -> cb.onOkCliked());
                AlertDialog alert =builder.create();
                alert.setTitle("Attenzione");
                alert.show();
            }
    }


    @AndroidEntryPoint
    public class OrdineViaggioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "SAVE_VALUE";
        private static final String MY_PREFS_CONFIG = "SAVE_VALUE_CONFIG";
        private EditText mViaggio, mData, mCodCliente;
        private ListView simpleList;
        private Button btnCambViaggio, btnContViaggio;
        private String idKeyArea, codViaggio, rootPath, idTerminale,riga;
        private AutoCompleteTextView act;
        private boolean flagFineArea;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterList;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        SharedPreferences prefs, prefsConfig;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    
        TempClass checkScaffale;
        MediaPlayer soundEffetctError, soundEffetctDistintaLetta, soundEffectWarning;
    
        @Inject
        ApiInterface apiInterface;
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ordine_viaggio);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.picking);
    
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            mViaggio = findViewById(R.id.viaggio);
            mData = findViewById(R.id.data);
            mCodCliente = findViewById(R.id.codiceCliente);
            simpleList = findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
            act = findViewById(R.id.elencoAree);
            btnCambViaggio = findViewById(R.id.btnCambViaggioOrdViag);
            btnContViaggio = findViewById(R.id.btnContinuaViaggioOrdViag);
    
            PickingDataService picking = new PickingDataService(OrdineViaggioActivity.this);
            checkScaffale = new TempClass(OrdineViaggioActivity.this);
    
            mViaggio.requestFocus();
            mViaggio.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
    
            btnContViaggio.setEnabled(false);
    
            prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = prefs.edit();
            prefsConfig = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_CONFIG, MODE_PRIVATE);
            rootPath = prefsConfig.getString("rootPath"," ");
            flagFineArea = prefs.getBoolean("flagFineArea",false);
            editor.putBoolean("flagTipoEtichetta",false).commit();
    
            DatiViaggioRepo dvr = new DatiViaggioRepo(apiInterface,OrdineViaggioActivity.this);
    
            if(!flagFineArea){
                try {
                    mViaggio.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    
                        }
                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                            if (s.length() == 10) {
                                editor.putBoolean("flagFineArea", false).commit();
                                idTerminale = prefsConfig.getString("idTerminale"," ");
    
                                codViaggio = mViaggio.getText().toString().trim();
                                editor.remove("isColloSciolto").clear();    
                                dvr.getDatiViaggio(rootPath,act,mViaggio,mData,mCodCliente,simpleList,btnContViaggio);
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    
                        }
                    });
    
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    
            } else{
                try {
                    mViaggio.setText(prefs.getString("codViaggio", " "));
                    editor.putBoolean("flagFineArea", false).commit();
                    Log.d("flagArea", "valore di flagArea " + String.valueOf(flagFineArea));
                    codViaggio = mViaggio.getText().toString().trim();
                    idTerminale = prefsConfig.getString("idTerminale"," ");
                    dvr.getDatiViaggio(rootPath,act,mViaggio,mData,mCodCliente,simpleList,btnContViaggio);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: That `flatMap` still runs on the IO thread which the body might not like. You'll have to move `observeOn(mainThread())` before it. Next, you have another API call which will needs its own `subscribeOn` to move off of the main thread.

Comment: I added ```.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())``` before flatmap and after subscribeOn.  Before .map I added a subscribeOn to manage the second API , but it doesn't work

Comment: `apiInterface.getAree(finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE).subscribeOn(...)` <---

Comment: Can I end it in this way apiInterface.getAree(finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())? I asked you that because this code is inside flapmap. I don't know how it works.

Comment: I did it, but it isn't working.. Any other suggestion?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: I have the same error. I modified my code in this way : ```return apiInterface.getAree(finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());```. I can't get   the condition <0 inside the flatmap. The condition > 0 works fine.

Comment: I don't understand. You can't get a negative response or you get a negative response but you still get that looper exception? For the former, check your API description for under what conditions it is supposed to return a negative reponse. For the latter case, please provide the **current source code** and the **full exception stacktrace**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253602/discussion-between-akarnokd-and-scripta14).

Comment: The first API call ```apiInterface.getInfoViaggio(HTTP_PATH_GETINFOVIAGGIO)``` returns a value.  Inside the flatmap, If < 0 it must execute a method and exit. It doesn't have to launch the second API. While if the value returned by the first call is > 0, the second call must also be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to akarnokd I found a solution to manage it in the right way.
I wanna share the solution and hope it'll be useful for someone.
Using flatMapMaybe and return Maybe.empty(), I can exit when the condition is <0.

```
String finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE = HTTP_PATH_GETAREE;
        disposable = apiInterface.getInfoViaggio(HTTP_PATH_GETINFOVIAGGIO)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMapMaybe(response -> {
                    if (response.getReturnCode() < 0){
                        Log.d("TAG1","response "+response.getReturnCode());
                        soundEffectError = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.wronglongbuzzer);
                        soundEffectError.start();
                        pulisciDatiViaggio(response.getReturnMessage());
                       return Maybe.empty();
                    }
                    else {
                        editor.putInt("out_rc", response.getReturnCode()).commit();
                        returnMessage = response.getReturnMessage();
                    }
                    return apiInterface.getAree(finalHTTP_PATH_GETAREE).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).toMaybe();
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(areas -> areas)
                .subscribe(this::handlerResponse,this::handlerError);
```